# Sklearn: Nearest Neightbour with String-Values and Custom Metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have data that looks like the following (all are string values)

```
>>> all_states[0:3]
[['A','B','Empty'],
 ['A', 'B', 'Empty'],
 ['C', 'D', 'Empty']]
```

I want to use a custom distance metric

```
def mydist(x, y):
    return 1
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, metric=mydist)
```

However, when I call

```
neigh.fit(np.array(all_states))
```

I get the error

**ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric**'

I know that I can use the `OneHotEncoder` or the `LabelEncoder` - but can I also do that without encoding the data as I have my own distance metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html),

> metrics tr or callable, default=’minkowski’
>
> The distance metric to usefor the tree. The default metric is minkowski, and with p=2 is
> equivalent to the standard Euclidean metric. See the documentation of
> DistanceMetric for a list of available metrics. If metric is
> “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix and must be square
> during fit. X may be a sparse graph, in which case only “nonzero”
> elements may be considered neighbors.

You can use [pdist documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and make it squareform as required for the input:

```
all_states = [['A','B','Empty'],
 ['A', 'B', 'Empty'],
 ['C', 'D', 'Empty']]

from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist,squareform
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

dm = squareform(pdist(all_states, mydist))
dm

array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])

neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, metric="precomputed")  
neigh.fit(dm)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ML models need to be trained on numerical data. If your distance metric has a way to convert your strings to numbers, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that to use [`neigh.kneighbors`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors) with `metric='precomputed'` and custom query points, pass `cdist(query_points, all_states)` to it ([cdist doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist)).
For example,

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

... # initialize and fit `neigh` as in @StupidWolf's answer
print(neigh.kneighbors(cdist(query_points, all_states)))
```